# Magento grid view show out of stock banner/label

Tags: magento-1.9, out-of-stock, manage-stock

I looked for this online and nothing worked.

I want a banner/label to show on my category view (in grid mode) that a certain product is out of stuck.

I tried to add:

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$qty = $stock->getQty();
if($qty <= 0)
{
<span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
}
```

after the foreach product in the grid mode but didn't work

---

**EDIT**

I also have something like this

```
<div class="product-secondary">
                    <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                    <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                        <p class="action"><a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('View Details')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="action availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);

if($stockItem->getIsInStock()):
{
    //in stock!
}
else
{
    //not in stock!
}
```

Comment: do I put that on grid mode after the foreach?

Comment: check my edited version. I have something like that look please

Comment: yes you can add after foreach

Comment: going to try and check. Do I need to reindex or is flushing the cache enough?

Comment: Still not working :/ It shows in list mode, but not in grid mode. And yes, I added after the foreach on the grid mode view area

Comment: line 123 https://pastebin.com/RkN4CjMx

Comment: Prashant Patel you there?

Comment: any error show ?

Comment: no error just doesnt show up on the grid view :/